# Generating function which has no singularity

Tags: generating-functions, singularity-theory

We can know the growth rate of coefficients from singularities of generating functions, but if a generating function which has no singularity at all, for example, the exponential function. What information can we get about its coefficients?

Comment: Since $e^z$ has radius of convergence $\infty$, I think you can use the formula found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) to figure out the asymptotics.  Or did you want something else?

Comment: What kind of generating function are you looking at? Exponential, Ordinary...?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Flajolet and Sedgewick's ["Analytic Combinatorics"](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) (PDF available for free), it contains a very thorough discussion of such matters. Somewhat more approachable is Sedgewick and Flajolet's ["Introduction to the analysis of algorithms"](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu).